# How to replicate multiple columns in an array from Raven DB to Relational Database using SQL Replication?

Tags: replication, ravendb

I am doing work to replicate our Raven DB documents into SQL using Raven's SQL Replication tool and only hit a couple of snags so far. I have now started work on one of our most complicated documents and struggling to find the best way to replicate arrays in the documents that contain multiple columns.

This is how the document I am attempting to replicate looks:

```
{
  "CreatedAt": "2013-03-26T15:58:05.5130458",
  "IsMostRecent": true,
  "ClientId": "clients/417",
  "StatusType": "Live",
  "Start": "2013-03-31T00:00:00.0000000",
  "End": null,
  "EndCharge": null,
  "AssessmentDate": null,
  "Correspondence": null,
  "Service": {
  "$type": "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.Personalisation, xxxx.Care.Core",
  "IsDirectBilling": false,
   "Visits": [
      {
         "DayOfWeek": "Monday",
         "Start": "09:00:00",
         "End": "10:15:00",
         "AdditionalResources": true,
         "SocialWork": {
             "Duration": 30,
             "BillableTo": "SocialWork",
             "VisitTasks": [
                "GoingToBed",
                "DressingAssistance",
                "WashingBathingAssistance",
                "AssistWithPersonalGrooming"
          ]
        },
         "PrivateWork": {
             "Duration": 45,
             "BillableTo": "Private",
          "VisitTasks": [
            "SupportWithRehab",
            "FoodPreperation",
            "ShoppingErrandRunning",
            "NonSpecialisedLaundry",
            "CheckVisit",
            "MealsAtHomeService",
            "Escorting"
          ]
        }
  },
  {
    "DayOfWeek": "Wednesday",
    "Start": "09:00:00",
    "End": "10:15:00",
    "AdditionalResources": true,
    "SocialWork": {
      "Duration": 30,
      "BillableTo": "SocialWork",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "GoingToBed",
        "DressingAssistance",
        "WashingBathingAssistance",
        "AssistWithPersonalGrooming"
      ]
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      "Duration": 45,
      "BillableTo": "Private",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "SupportWithRehab",
        "FoodPreperation",
        "ShoppingErrandRunning",
        "NonSpecialisedLaundry",
        "CheckVisit",
        "MealsAtHomeService",
        "Escorting"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "DayOfWeek": "Friday",
    "Start": "09:00:00",
    "End": "10:15:00",
    "AdditionalResources": true,
    "SocialWork": {
      "Duration": 30,
      "BillableTo": "SocialWork",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "GoingToBed",
        "DressingAssistance",
        "WashingBathingAssistance",
        "AssistWithPersonalGrooming"
      ]
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      "Duration": 45,
      "BillableTo": "Private",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "SupportWithRehab",
        "FoodPreperation",
        "ShoppingErrandRunning",
        "NonSpecialisedLaundry",
        "CheckVisit",
        "MealsAtHomeService",
        "Escorting"
      ]
    }
  }
],
"_visits": [
  {
    "DayOfWeek": "Monday",
    "Start": "09:00:00",
    "End": "10:15:00",
    "AdditionalResources": true,
    "SocialWork": {
      "Duration": 30,
      "BillableTo": "SocialWork",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "GoingToBed",
        "DressingAssistance",
        "WashingBathingAssistance",
        "AssistWithPersonalGrooming"
      ]
    },
    "PrivateWork": {
      "Duration": 45,
      "BillableTo": "Private",
      "VisitTasks": [
        "SupportWithRehab",
        "FoodPreperation",
        "ShoppingErrandRunning",
        "NonSpecialisedLaundry",
        "CheckVisit",
        "MealsAtHomeService",
        "Escorting"
      ]
    }
   },
 }
}
```

This is my replication script so far, currently some columns are being replicated but not all:

```
replicateToServiceStatusDetails({
        ClientId: this.ClientId,
        StatusType: this.StatusType,
        Start: this.Start,
        End: this.End,
        EndChargeDate: this.EndChargeDate,
        AssessmentDate: this.AssessmentDate
});

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.length; i++) 
{
    replicateToService( 
    {
           IsDirectBilling: this.IsDirectBilling
    });
}

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.length; i++) 
{
    replicateToVisits( 
    {
            DayOfWeek: this.Service.Visits.DayOfWeek,
    Start: this.Service.Visits.Start,
    End: this.Service.Visits.End,
    AdditionalResources: this.Service.Visits.AdditionalResources
});
}

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.SocialWork.length; i++) 
{
    replicateToSocialWork( 
    {
            Duration: this.Service.Visits.SocialWork.Duration,
    BillableTo: this.Service.Visits.SocialWork.BillableTo
    });
}

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.PrivateWork.length; i++) 
{
    replicateToPrivateWork( 
    {
            Duration: this.Service.Visits.PrivateWork.Duration,
    BillableTo: this.Service.Visits.PrivateWork.BillableTo
    });
}
```

Looking for some ideas on how to get all columns replicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need `for` if you are iterating over arrays. This is probably how you want to do this:

```
replicateToServiceStatusDetails({
        ClientId: this.ClientId,
        StatusType: this.StatusType,
        Start: this.Start,
        End: this.End,
        EndChargeDate: this.EndChargeDate,
        AssessmentDate: this.AssessmentDate
});

replicateToService( 
{
       IsDirectBilling: this.IsDirectBilling
});

for (var i=0; i<this.Service.Visits.length; i++) 
{
    var visit = this.Service.Visits[i];
    replicateToVisits( 
    {
            DayOfWeek: visit.DayOfWeek,
            Start: visit.Start,
            End: visit.End,
            AdditionalResources: visit.AdditionalResources
    });

    replicateToSocialWork( 
    {
            Duration: visit.SocialWork.Duration,
        BillableTo: visit.SocialWork.BillableTo
    });

    replicateToPrivateWork( 
    {
         Duration: visit.PrivateWork.Duration,
        BillableTo: visit.PrivateWork.BillableTo
    });
}
```

Comment: Fantastic Ayende, this has worked and given me a clearer picture of how to use this for my other documents. No stopping RavenDB :) Thanks again.